# System.Drawing.Font - change Letter Spacing?

Tags: .net, fonts, drawing, system.drawing

Using `System.Drawing.Font`, is there a way to change the Letter Spacing, just like you can change the Font Size?

I'm looking to increase the letter spacing to fit a specific width.

If this is not possible, are there alternatives to get the desired effect? For example, is there an easy way of having multiple graphics which will fit my specific width?

Comment: Where are you using this font? What is making use of it?

Comment: It's being use in a GDI+ image, with `Graphics.DrawString()`

Comment: There is no built-in mechanism in `System.Drawing` for drawing text with adjusted letter spacing. You will have to roll your own code for that. Start by looking at `MeasureCharacterRanges`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think DrawString will allow you to specify anything as detailed as the spacing between characters, but I would create a helper function that calculates spacing based on a desired width and then draw each character to fit.

Try this and see how you get on...

```
    public void DrawSpacedText(Graphics g, Font font, Brush brush, PointF point, string text, int desiredWidth)
    {
        //Calculate spacing
        float widthNeeded = 0;
        foreach (char c in text)
        {
            widthNeeded += g.MeasureString(c.ToString(), font).Width;
        }
        float spacing = (desiredWidth - widthNeeded) / (text.Length - 1);

        //draw text
        float indent = 0;
        foreach (char c in text)
        {
            g.DrawString(c.ToString(), font, brush, new PointF(point.X + indent, point.Y));
            indent += g.MeasureString(c.ToString(), font).Width + spacing;
        }
    }
```

You could probably optimise this to make only one call to MeasureString per character. Or even use MeasureCharacterRanges to get an array (which I believe is more accurate anyway)

**Edit**: Here is an example using MeasureCharacterRanges instead...

```
    public void DrawSpacedText(Graphics g, Font font, Brush brush, PointF point, string text, int desiredWidth)
    {
        //Calculate spacing
        float widthNeeded = 0;
        Region[] regions = g.MeasureCharacterRanges(text, font, new RectangleF(point, new SizeF(desiredWidth, font.Height + 10)), StringFormat.GenericDefault);
        float[] widths = new float[regions.Length];
        for(int i = 0; i < widths.Length; i++)
        {
            widths[i] = regions[i].GetBounds(g).Width;
            widthNeeded += widths[i];
        }
        float spacing = (desiredWidth - widthNeeded) / (text.Length - 1);

        //draw text
        float indent = 0;
        int index = 0;
        foreach (char c in text)
        {
            g.DrawString(c.ToString(), font, brush, new PointF(point.X + indent, point.Y));
            indent += widths[index] + spacing;
            index++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 This is a nice way to do it. However, having constant spacing screws up [text kerning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning), which is difficult to achieve properly. In other words, results won't be as *visually pleasing* as with proper kerning, to quote Wikipedia.

Comment: This is somewhat naive approach assuming one character === glyph. No bidi, no ligatures and so on. Just lower half of ASCII table.

Comment: @olegz If the only intent is to measure the string and not draw it, would it suffice?

Comment: @pelican_george, the answer is yes unless the string contains CJK characters, diacritical marks or you want the code to be i18n friendly

Comment: How would you approach this to have it i18n friendly?

Answer (score 1):

This code supports a new line in the text and returns an Image object.

```
public static Image ConvertTextToImage(String text, Font font, Color textColor, int spacing = 0)
{
    var textParts = SplitOnBreakLines(text);
    // dummy image, just create drawing
    var img = new Bitmap(1, 1);
    var drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);
    // calculate width, height
    var width = 0.0F;
    foreach (char c in text)
    {
        width += drawing.MeasureString(c.ToString(), font).Width;
    }           
    width = (width + spacing * (ClearBreakLines(text).Length - 1))  / textParts.Length;
    if (width <= 0)
        width = 1;
    var height = font.Height * textParts.Length;
    // clear and create new objects
    img.Dispose();
    drawing.Dispose();

    img = new Bitmap((int)width, (int)height);
    drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);

    //Adjust for high quality
    drawing.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    drawing.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
    drawing.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    drawing.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    drawing.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;

    //paint the background
    drawing.Clear(Color.Transparent);

    //create a brush for the text
    var textBrush = new SolidBrush(textColor);
    //write text
    var indent = 0.0F;
    var point = new Point();            
    foreach (var textPart in textParts)
    {
        foreach (char c in textPart)
        {
            drawing.DrawString(c.ToString(), font, textBrush, new PointF(point.X + indent, point.Y));
            indent += drawing.MeasureString(c.ToString(), font).Width + spacing;
        }
        indent = 0.0F;
        point.Y += font.Height;
    }
    drawing.Save();
    textBrush.Dispose();
    drawing.Dispose();
    return img;           
}

public static string ClearBreakLines(string s)
{
    return Regex.Replace(s, @"\r\n?|\n", string.Empty);
}

public static string[] SplitOnBreakLines(string s)
{
    return Regex.Split(s, @"\r\n?|\n");           
}
```